# create a dataframe using headings and text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file in the following format:

Heading 1

Some text here

Heading 2

Some text here

Heading 3

Some text here

I need to create a dataframe in the format

df=

| Heading | text |
| --- | --- |
| Heading 1 | Some text here |
| Heading 2 | Some text here |
| Heading 3 | Some text here |

Comment: is the file just a text file?

Comment: Yes it is a txt file

Comment: How to make the difference between an heading and text?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    data = [line.strip() for line in fp if line.strip()]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data[::2], data[1::2])), columns=['Heading', 'text'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Heading            text
0  Heading 1  Some text here
1  Heading 2  Some text here
2  Heading 3  Some text here
```

Content of `data.txt` file:

```
Heading 1

Some text here

Heading 2

Some text here

Heading 3

Some text here
```

Comment: This one is more robust and clears the empty lines (Not mentioning does not import other libraries). But it would be awesome if you could explain why this code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the file has **Header** in odd and **text** in even rows:

You first read the whole data and create a `numpy` array. Then you can reshape it to be `nx2`. Last but not least you create a data frame from it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open("data.dat", "r") as the_file:
    data = np.array([d.strip() for d in the_file])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape((-1, 2)), columns=["Heading", "text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following could be adapted if you want to understand the way of structuring your code.

```
df= DataFrame()
header=[]
text=[]
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for f_line in f.readlines():
        if f_line.startswith("Header"):
            header.append(f_line.rstrip())
        else:
            text.append(f_line.rstrip())
    df['header']=header
    df['text']=text
```